# Set two different ranges and execute code

Tags: excel

I'd appreciate any help as I have no experience in vba.

What I'm trying to do
is that at the sheet "data" when the selected cell belongs to the rng1 then
the value for example 020318 at the cell changes to take the format 02/03/18.

At the same time in column ED at each cell there is a sum formula.
When this sum is under zero then a msgbox should pop up

for example

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("I3:I1000,O3:O1000,P3:P1000,AE3:AE1000,AF3:AF1000,AH3:AH1000,AI3:AI1000")
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("ED3:ED1000")
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("I3:I1000,O3:O1000,P3:P1000,AE3:AE1000,AF3:AF1000,AH3:AH1000,AI3:AI1000")) Is Nothing Then
For Each cell In rng1
If cell <> "" Then
If Len(cell) = 6 Then
cell.Value = Format(cell.Value, "00/00/00")
End If
End If
Next cell

For Each cell In rng2
If IsNumeric(cell) = True Then
If cell.Value < 0 Then MsgBox "Τhe salary " & Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value & "  before ....is " & Cells(cell.Row, 3).Value & " try more", vbCritical, "XXXXX"
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, can you please edit your question with information about what seems to be the problem with your current code and what line is the error on in case there's one ? I also recommend adding vba and excel-vba tags for better visibility of your question.

Comment: Wel come to SO. Just wondering, but `cell.Value = Format(cell.Value, "00/00/00")`, I think this line should be `cell.Value = Format(CDate(Left(cell.Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(cell.Value, 3, 2) & "/" & "20" & Right(cell.Value, 2)), "dd/mm/yy")`. Anyways, you should post an exmaple of your data and maybe we can help better

Comment: I'll try to become more specific with a simple example. Cell A1 takes a numeric value for example 1000 and B1 a text value for examlpe Tom. In cell C1 user instead of typing date as dd/mm/yy to type only ddmmyy and automatically convert to date format. Secondly in cell d1 there is a calculate formula that gives  positive or negative results.if the result is negative number (<0) then a pop up message will inform the user, by showing the negative value and the name in b1, that sth goes wrong. The above must cover a range of 1000 cells.